# What's wrong with editing in TinyMCE?

Tags: html, tinymce

I've noticed now after implementing TinyMCE on my site that when I'm editing it doesn't read HTML the way a normal editor does it, like Dreamweaver.

It's a little tough to describe exactly what's wrong but let's say I've got two tables on each side of a frame. Even though I've created them exactly the same, the attributes are different until I edit "table properties" and remove the extra code that the editor puts in "style".

This is just an example of many. I'm starting to think I'm just stupid, but I was hoping someone could explain to me why this is?

When I look into the database the code looks absolutely horrible :) Is that much code really necessary just to write simple HTML?

Comment: Most WYSIWYG editors will make modifications to the HTML code, and tend to screw it up.  Look at Word for a good example.  Dreamweaver is not a "normal" editor.

Comment: Welcome to the world of WYSIPWYGBNHYWI (what-you-see-is-probably-what-you-get-but-not-how-you-want-it) editors. Sounds exactly like my normal experience with Dreamweaver. If you want good HTML, do it yourself.

Comment: I like DWs code highlighting in code view (which is all I use it for). I imagine the OP needs to be able to post HTML on a webpage to a database, hence the question.

Comment: As a more serious suggestion, you may want to look into WYSIWYM languages like Markdown (which Stackoverflow uses) or ReST. They consistently produce better output than drag and drop visual editors could ever hope to achieve.

Comment: I love your answers :) The thing is that I want to use TinyMCE because the person who's gonna run the site doesn't know anything about html/css/php whatever, so I figured a "WYSIPWYGBNHYWI"-editor would do the trick. But it's pretty f*cked =) Is there a better way than using the method I'm using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short of hand-composing/editing your markup, you're not going to get perfectly simple and straight forward markup with any editor. Some are more atrocious than others (Word, I'm looking at you), but some editors do allow you to output XHTML-compliant markup, which I think is better than the markup soup you get otherwise.

You can checkout WYMeditor:

http://www.wymeditor.org/

And, depending on your needs, MarkItUp could also be useful:

http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/home/

Also, Markdown:

http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/

**EDIT**

As your comment suggests, you may not be interested in switching from TinyMCE (although I think you should look at WYMeditor).

Take a look at the configuration options:

http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/Configuration

Specifically:

http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/Configuration:inline_styles

http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/Configuration:valid_elements

http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/Configuration:invalid_elements

http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/Configuration:extended_valid_elements

Comment: Great answer man! I'm gonna check those editors out, seems there are a bunch of these on the web and it's pretty hard to choose when you're new. Isn't there a standard editor that everyone agrees is pretty decent when working with simple html? :) Thanks.

Comment: Eh... I don't know if there's a consensus (at least not one I know of), but the two I listed plus deceze's mention of Markdown are considered solid if at times limited editors. The more an editor tries to emulate Word, the more trouble it gets into in the markup. I've setup TinyMCE to literally only allow like P and SPAN tags with simple inline bold and italic styles. So you can get TinyMCE to produce somewhat decent markup, you just have to cripple it.

Comment: Tinymce can be configured in most cases to fit a users wishes, but it might be difficult to find out the correct init parameters